# How are the correct tRNAs transported to the ribosome?

Tags: biochemistry, translation, ribosome

I have been trying to understand how the tRNA transporting the correct amino acid required by the ribosome reaches the ribosome. The only way I can imagine this happening is that all types of tRNA+amino acid reach the ribosome, bombard the ribosome, and the ribosome will 'accept' only the one that matches what it is waiting for.

I can not imagine any other mechanism in the cell's cytoplasm that will somehow filter or push the correct tRNA+amino acid and move it towards the ribosome that needs it.

How do we explain this mystery?

Answer (score 1):

> The only way I can imagine this happening is that all types of tRNA+amino acid reach the ribosome, bombarding the ribosome, and the ribosome will 'accept' only the one that matches what it is waiting for.

Yup, basically.  [This is an extremely cool figure](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/94/Protein_translation.gif) showing the process. There are various elongation factors that aid the process, such as EF-Tu, which essentially waits until there is a good codon-anticodon match before hydrolyzing GTP and allowing the tRNA/amino acid to enter the ribosome.

This process can be particularly salient when you look at a concept such as codon-usage bias.  Certain tRNAs are more common in the cell, so if a given mRNA uses codons to match those tRNA instead of matching other degenerate but less common anti-codons, translation will occur faster.  This is more obvious in organisms such as *E. coli* where growth is paramount.

Comment: Apart from random movement, are there any other factors which move the tRNA near the ribosome, where the ones you mentioned take effect?